# How to declare HDF5r attribute data type: Transferring data between R and Python

Tags: python, r, hdf5

## Issue

I have a data set I am trying to use to create an H5 file I can pass to a Python package. I am populating the attributes using the function `attr(object=,attr_name=) <- value`. However, when I try to load my attributes for each object in the group within my h5 file, it appears the data class is not being preserved. When I open my h5 file in Python with {h5py} and look at the attributes every object is defined as fallows `dtype=object`. Does anyone know if this is a default of the `attr()` function? If so, should I try to use the `create_attr()` instead?

Thanks for any and all help! I recommend running this in Rmarkdown so you can make one r chunk and one python chunk for each of my blocks of code.

## Reprex - edited

I am providing a simplified version of the code with sample data for three objects/events within the first group.

These events house a 3x6000 matrix each.

Each matrix should have 3 attributes each - a numeric, a char, and a list

Edits

1. The reticulate package will be used at the end of the r chunk to pass the path to the h5 file you created in R to the Python chunk.
2. Removed the list format from the purrr functions, functions working cleanly now.

#### R Code for Creating the File

```
library(hdf5r)
library(dplyr)
library(reticulate)

h5_file_path = here::here() # path to where you are creating the h5 file 

# This line creates the empty file
NMTSO_trainer.h5 <- H5File$new(filename = sprintf("%s/NMTSO_trainer.h5", h5_file_path), mode = "a")

# This creates a group within the file, think of the file as a directory tree and each group is like folder 
data.grp <- NMTSO_trainer.h5$create_group("data")

# Items to populate attribues
trace_name = c("sample_event1", "sample_event2", "sample_event3")
col_names = c("att1", "att2", "att3")
value = list(runif(n = 1, -100, 100), "SC", list(c(0,0,runif(n = 1, 0, 5))))

# Place holder for the matrices per event
x = list()

events = length(trace_name)

# Populates the event matrices
for (i in 1:events){
  x[[i]] <- runif(n = 6000, -1, 1) %>% matrix(nrow = 1)
  x[[i]] <- rep(0,(2 * 6000)) %>% matrix(nrow = 2) %>% rbind(x[[i]])
}

# Puts each matrix within the corresponding "folder" in the h5 file
purrr::map2(trace_name, x, function(trace_name, x){
  data.grp[[trace_name]] <- x
})

# Puts the corresponding attributes with each matrix - there should be 3 per matrix. 
# This is where I am wondering if I should use create_attr() rather than h5attr()
purrr::walk(trace_name, function(trace_name){
  purrr::walk2(col_names, value, function(col_names, value){
    h5attr(data.grp[[trace_name]], col_names) <- value
  })
})

# Shows the class of the objects pupulated in the h5 file according to R
h5attr(data.grp[[trace_name[1]]], col_names[1]) %>% class()
h5attr(data.grp[[trace_name[1]]], col_names[2]) %>% class()
h5attr(data.grp[[trace_name[1]]], col_names[3]) %>% class()

# The file must be closed for all data to be written to the file
NMTSO_trainer.h5$close_all(close_self = TRUE)

py$file_path = sprintf("%s/NMTSO_trainer.h5", h5_file_path)
```

#### Python Chunk for Evaluating Attr Format

Edits

1. Passed  the file_path object created in R into the Python environment using the reticulate package. No longer requires any user file_path manipulation as long as the code is ran in Rstudio's Rmarkdown files to take advantage of R's Python engine.

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

e = h5py.File(file_path, 'r')

# Shows the users what groups are in the file 
list(e.keys())

group = e['data']

# Shows the user what events are in the group
list(group.keys())

# Shows the user what is in the attributes 
group['sample_event1'].attrs['att1']
group['sample_event1'].attrs['att2']
group['sample_event1'].attrs['att3']

# Shows the user what format the data is in
type(group['sample_event1'].attrs['att1'])
type(group['sample_event1'].attrs['att2'])
type(group['sample_event1'].attrs['att3'])
```

Comment: HDF5 supports scalar attributes, and h5py can create and read them. So, that's not why you get `dtype=object`. I am not familiar with R or hdf5r, so only know what the docs say. Briefly, the attributes API "`allows interactions with HDF5-attributes in a way similar to regular R-object attributes in R.`" Do R-object attributes have properties that mean they need to be saved as arrays instead of scalars?

Comment: I don't know too much about the inner workings of R as I am fully self-taught by practice rather than reading. However, I was looking at the {reticulate} package, R's package to communicate with Python and they show object equivalents between the languages. https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate. I know R's basic object structure is a vector. A single element vector is equivalent to a scalar in Python. I also attempted using reticulate to convert all my objects to their Python equivalents and populating my attributes with those. yielded the same results.

Answer (score 0):

## Half Solution/Work Around

So I found if I use {reticulate} to create the hdf5 file in Python rather than R, the attributes I create retain their formatting after closing the file and reopening them.  As I have built my pipeline in R, this is not the most ideal solution. If anyone knows how to do this with {HDF5r} rather than {h5py}, I would love to learn.

Remaining Question

The first attribute's type returns as a float64, I believe the standard for R. Is there a simple way to convert to float32? Is it necessary to convert between them? I have an exemplary file that goes to a program and the float attributes are float32.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reticulate)

h5_file_path = sprintf("%s/NMTSO_test.h5", here::here())

# Items to populate attribues
trace_name = c("sample_event1", "sample_event2", "sample_event3")
col_names = c("att1", "att2", "att3")
value = list(runif(n = 1, -100, 100), "SC", list(c(0,0,runif(n = 1, 0, 5))))

# Place holder for the matrices per event
x = list()

events = length(trace_name)

# Populates the event matrices
for (i in 1:events){
  x[[i]] <- runif(n = 6000, -1, 1) %>% matrix(nrow = 1)
  x[[i]] <- rep(0,(2 * 6000)) %>% matrix(nrow = 2) %>% rbind(x[[i]])
  
rm(events)
rm(i)
}

reticulate::repl_python()

import h5py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# instert path inplace of my path here
e = h5py.File(''+r.h5_file_path, 'w')

# loop to create and fill each event in the group with values from the R object 'x'
for i in np.r_[0:len(r.trace_name)]:
  e.create_dataset("data/"+ r.trace_name[i], r.x[i].shape, data=r.x[i], dtype=np.float32)

# loops to populate the attributes in each sample_event from the R object 'value'
for i in np.r_[0:len(r.trace_name)]:
  for j in np.r_[0:len(r.col_names)]:
    e['data/'+r.trace_name[i]].attrs[''+r.col_names[j]] = r.value[j]

# Shows the user what is in the attributes 
e['data/sample_event1'].attrs['att1']
e['data/sample_event1'].attrs['att2']
e['data/sample_event1'].attrs['att3']

# Shows the user what format the data is in
type(e['data/sample_event1'].attrs['att1'])
type(e['data/sample_event1'].attrs['att2'])
type(e['data/sample_event1'].attrs['att3'])

e.close()

exit
```

Comment: Only difference between float64 and float32 is precision. In general it is not necessary to convert unless a routine requires 1 or the other. A Google search will discover multiple answers to do this.